# Cómo solucionar el zoom en el navegador al dibujar con canvas usando el puntero del mouse

Tags: javascript, canvas

estoy tratando de calcar una imagen y pasarlo al canvas pero cuando le doy zoom al navegador para tener mejor visualización del dibujo, el circulo que dibujo en canvas se pierde, o sea si hago clic en cualquier área, el circulo se dibuja unos pixeles arriba, esto sucede cuando hago zoom en el navegador. Alguien sabe como solucionar este problema?

Aquí una imagen, el punto del mouse no aparece pero cuando voy trazando las orillas de una imagen al hacer zoom el circulo que dibujo con canvas no coincide con  el puntero del mouse, esto significa que se dibuja unos pixeles mas arriba
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código para dibujar un circulo cada vez que hago clic en cualquier area del dibujo, para asi obtener las coordenadas no mas exacta posible:

```js
var cadena ="";  
var circle;
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  return {
    x: evt.clientX,
    y: evt.clientY
  };
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://picsum.photos/640/360";           

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
  var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
  var message = 'posicion del mouse: x: ' + mousePos.x + ', y: ' + mousePos.y;
  cadena+= mousePos.x;
  cadena+= ',';
  cadena+= mousePos.y;
  cadena+= ',';
  console.log(cadena);

  circle.beginPath();
  circle.arc(mousePos.x-7,mousePos.y-7,5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
  circle.fill();
}, false);

(function(){
   circle = canvas.getContext('2d');
   circle.fillStyle ="black";         
})();
img.onload = function(){
context.drawImage(img, 100, 50);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="700" style="background-color:black">
```

Comment: Esto *funciona correctamente para mi* si le doy zoom a la ventana del navegador. Otra cosa sería si estas utilizando `scale` en el CSS. En este caso tienes que multiplicar `mousePos.x * scale.x` y `mousePos.y * scale.y`. En el caso en el cual estás redimensionando el contexto del canvas tienes que dividir `mousePos.x / scale.x`. Lo mismo para y

Comment: Un comentario más: si tienes que calcar un mapa en lugar de hacerlo de esta manera puedes utilizar mapas de https://d-maps.com/. Lo sacas en formato SVG y después utilizas los trazados SVG en el canvas. Para esto necesitas `path2d`: [Trazados SVG en canvas](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/canvas/path2d.php)

Comment: voy a intentar lo que me recomendaste, lo que me llevo hacer el diseño de la republica era que con registros de la base de datos los estados pudieran cambiar de color de acuerdo a las zonas de riesgo de delincuencia, y no se me ocurrio otra idea para hacer ese proyecto, otra como tu dices era usar svg pero no logre cambiar el color de acuerdo a las zonas y me lleve un buen dolor de cabeza. Gracias voy a intentar lo que me dices